# How to generate Unique ID from same values

Tags: java, database, algorithm, hash

I need to find a way that a set of values will always generate the same ID and it needs to be unique.

The main reason for this is to speed up queries where before I needed to do a lot of joins, to only one comparision. I know my domain and sadly the values are not closed (i.e., they can be about anything).

I tryied with hash, but by definition, hash functions don't guarantee uniquiness. Is there a way?

**EDIT: Some more context**

I am working in a system that correlate Events coming from different set of devices.

The correlation is calculated through some of the Events attributes:

- From where it came from.
- What kind of event it is.
- Values that come from it and that differs the same kind of events in different groups.

For example, think of something like this. Imagine my device is a refrigerator. It sends events about the temperature and food that are inside of it. So, imagine we receive events in this order:

```
Event1: {type: temperature, values: [{temperature: -1]}
Event2: {type: food, values: [{group: vegetable, name: brocollis, quantity: 2, weight: 0.1]}
Event3: {type: food, values: [{group: vegetable, name: lettuce, quantity: 1,  weight: 0.1]}
Event4: {type: temperature, values: [{temperature: -5]}
```

All events of type `temperature` must be correlated, but of type `food` the correlation is also given from the its `name` and `group`. I.e., the number of correlation identifiers is variable.

This correlations are saved in a structure like this

```
@Entity
public class EventCorrelation {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Audit
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
       name = "evt_corr_extra_id",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "correlation_id"))
    @Column(name = "extra_id")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Collection<String> identifiers;
    // getters/setters
}
```

It's inside the identifiers array that I save the values that identify the correlation. I want to speed up the query that search for an event correlation and my first idea was to create an unique id from the correlation `identifiers`.

I have a knowledge database that knows that from a given event, certain attribute is a correlation identifier.

Any tips?

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more context in order to get a good answer. What kind of input data do you have, and what kind of output do you need? Since you mention queries and joins, is this actually a SQL question and not Java?

Comment: Also, you are not quite right that hashes by definition don't guarantee uniqueness. A hash without collisions is called a 'perfect hash', and is quite possible to devise if you know the full input set.

Comment: Ok. Will give more context. And I know, but that the perfect hash can be created. But sadly I don't know ALL the input set, but part of it.

Comment: Why do you need to always generate the same ID? Usually you can add an ID field to one of your tables which is a monotonically increasing number. This guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: Speed up of queries could be after optimizing explain plan.

Comment: Missing something here, give us a bit of an example.

Comment: @AdrianGrigo For this purposes better suited such an objects called sequence.

Comment: You mentioned that your domain and values are not closed. Could you limit it at least to set of currently known types and values?. This set should grow for a while and then stabilize after a while of having your system running. Would it help while constructing your ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to convert your values to Strings and concatenate them using some kind of reserved delimiter, making sure to preserve ordering. The String becomes your unique id.

For example, the values 1, "Bob", 7383.234, "{asdf}", and 2013-01-08 would have the following unique id:

```
"1|Bob|7383.234|{asdf}|2013-01-08"
```

This is a kind of [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) technique.

Comment: This is the only solution which can be used after-the-fact, as a search key.  That is not true of any of the suggestions being given above.

Comment: the problem is that I can't guarantee the values order :/

Comment: @RalfHoppen what do you mean by that?  They're just a collection of strings without order?  Then order them.  Sort them by whatever, and you'll have a repeatable order.

Comment: Yeah, can't think of another way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For example two food events:

```
Event11: {type: food, values: [{group: vegetable, name: brocollis, quantity: 2, weight: 0.1]}
Event12: {type: food, values: [{group: vegetable, name: brocollis, quantity: 3, weight: 0.27]}
```

Could it  be that both events are for brocollis, but quantity and  weight are not part of ID? 
I assume this is answered by your *knowledge database that knows that from a given event, certain attribute is a correlation identifier*

Once you have set of attributes for ID, let say {type, group, name}, you could sort them and build ID from them. For example "{group:vegetable,name:broccolis,type:food}" = ID is string, attributes are ordered by attribute name.

Btw, you mentioned that your domain is not closed, but the fact that you have knowledge database should mean that this limits allowed *types* to only known set. So at least for types, you should be able to find some numerical value representing type, if you'd like to make ID bit shorter.

Comment: you are correct in your assumption. `quantity` and `weight` are not included in the correlation calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is creating dictionary of strings. For each unique **string** you will get a unique **id** in this dictionary. But this method causes decreasing of performance and increasing the memory usage.

**EDIT 1**: By the way, one possible idea is using a native `String`'s object id. I mean, that in Java all strings are natively cached. So, you could try to use its native hashes, which are linked with memory addresses of its objects. Something like using `System.identityHashCode()`.

**EDIT 2:** In my previous statement I was not quite accurate about string's cache. In any way you could create such a cache manually (using `HashMap`), and then use a cached value object in `System.identityHashCode()`

Comment: Could you describe in more detail how System.identityHashCode() would be better that String.hashCode()? It looks that System.identityHashCode() can be any value and could change between different runs of program. String.hashCode() is actually well defined and should be stable.

Comment: @ArnostValicek, this doesn't matter, if all strings will be loaded into the memory after each run of program. This is such kind of DB-in-memory decision.